# valueError zero length field name in format

Tags: python

I am using python version 2.7.3 and im trying to print out some information with a certain format.

```
final="<".join('< {} >'.format(' '.join(items)) for items in list)
```

But i got a valueError zero length field name in format error, is this because my python version does not allow certain syntaxs?

Comment: So what python version do you use? How exactly does `board` look?

Comment: You'll have to post the full traceback and more code, what you've posted works fine.

Comment: I tried this with `board` being a list. Is it really an integer? With an integer I get: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: just Edited the code with board added in.

Comment: This works fine in 2.7.3, you must be using 2.6.

Comment: @PavelAnossov what changes must I make for 2.6?

Comment: See gnibbler's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pyhon2.6 requires you to put a positional argument in the `{}`

```
'< {0} >'.format(' '.join(items))
```